# MySQL/C# getting specific data

Tags: c#, mysql

Ok so my database/table is setup like this: 
`id, username, password, level`
I'd like to be able to do the following when you press a button.

Enter username and password in textbox1 + 2
press button
it matches that username and password to their set "level" which in this case could be admin at which point it changes to the admin_form1, if you're just a member it switches to member_form1 etc, etc.

I've tried using `string sql = "Select level from TABLE where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'";`
with 0 luck,

any help would be appreciated!

I'm not good with MySQL which is the problem

```
string sql = "Select active_subscriptions from Usertable where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=server;database=database;uid=username;pwd=password;");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);

            con.Open();

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                MessageBox.Show(reader.GetString("admin"));
            }
```

Comment: PLEASE USE PARAMETERISED QUERY. Also, paste the code how you actually executed this SQL via C#

Comment: When you say you had no luck, what exactly happened - theres no c# code here to show how you used your query, did you get errors? or what

Comment: I actually got it working, posting source now :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with `;` at the of the sentence

I've tried using string sql = "Select level from TABLE where username='" + textBox1.Text + "' and password='" + textBox2.Text + "'**;**";

Comment: I think the trouble is I can't actually output this information, do you think you could write the c# and sql code out for me to paste? again I think its just my bad code